# syncing 900 devices to a server

Tags: sync, rsync

Once a day I sync 200 devices from a central server through the internet using rsync. All devices sync to the content on the central server. The updates vary from a 100k to 200MB per day.  I need to increase the number of devices to 900. I am concerned that this will not work with rsync and I am looking for some advice on what technology I should be looking at.

Thank you

Comment: Have you evaluated owncloud?